# How to redefine a key in SBT?

Tags: scala, key, sbt

How can you redefine a key in SBT (as opposed to extend or define)?

I currently have the following in my build script (project/build.scala):

```
fullClasspath in Runtime <<= (fullClasspath in Runtime, classDirectory in Compile) map { (cp, classes) => (cp.files map {
  f: File =>
    if (f.getName == classes.getName) {
      val result = new File(f.getParent + File.separator + "transformed-" + f.getName)
      if (result.exists) result else f
    } else f
}).classpath }
```

It extends the classpath in Runtime by adding, for each directory in Compile, a new directory with the same name but with `transformed-` prepended to the front.

(If you are wondering why, I have a plugin which performs program transformation on the bytecode after compilation but before packaging, and selective recompilation gets very confused if you overwrite the original files.)

My problem is the following: This extends the original key, and therefore the classpath contains the original directories from Compile, plus the renamed copies, but I only want the renamed ones from Compile.

I tried to do something along the lines of

```
fullClasspath in Runtime := ...
```

but I don't know what to put on the right-hand side.

---

I've marked the answer since it lead me directly to the solution, but my final solution was to modify the above code snippet to the following

```
fullClasspath in Runtime := (fullClasspath in Runtime).value.files.map {
  f: File =>
    if (f.getName == (classDirectory in Compile).value.getName) {
      val result = new File(f.getParent + File.separator + "transformed-" + f.getName)
      if (result.exists) result else f
    } else f
}.classpath
```

which does exactly what I wanted, and is slightly better style.

Comment: Glad you now have working code — but I actually don't know why or how your new code would behave any differently than your original code! They seem equivalent to me. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @SethTisue Suppose `(classDirectory in Compile).value.contains{_.getName == "outputDirectory"}`. Then, using the first code snippet, `(fullClasspath in Runtime).value.files.contains{_.getName == "outputDirectory"}` _and_ `(fullClasspath in Runtime).value.files.contains{_.getName == "transformed-outputDirectory"}`. However, with the second snippet, only the second of these tests is true. If I have understood correctly, this is because `<<=` adds to what was on the classpath before, whereas `:=` overwrites the old classpath.

Comment: There is no such difference between `<<=` and `:=`. The latter is just magic macro sugar for the former. I repeated the experiment in my answer just now using `<<=` and the outcome was the same. (I have edited the answer to say so.)

Comment: @SethTisue I've reread the documentation, and agree. Sorry about that. I have no idea then why the original code snippet is wrong. (It definitely is---I've tried.) A guess is that has something to do with `classDirectory in Compile` being mapped over in the original snippet, but not latter. How this changes things I'm not sure. It's in these cases why I don't really believe SBT is all that simple after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little experiment I did just now at the sbt command line showing that it's definitely possible to remove something unwanted from `fullClasspath`:

```
% sbt
> show runtime:fullClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(.../target/classes),
            Attributed(.../jars/scala-library-2.10.4.jar),
            Attributed(.../jars/asm-all-3.3.1.jar))
> set fullClasspath in Runtime := (fullClasspath in Runtime).value.files.filterNot(_.getName.containsSlice("asm")).classpath
> show runtime:fullClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(.../target/classes),
            Attributed(.../jars/scala-library-2.10.4.jar))
```

Voila — the "asm-all-3.3.1" entry is gone.

Note that this isn't about `<<=` vs `:=`. The latter is just macro-based sugar for the former. The experiment turns out the same if I avoid `:=` and do this instead:

```
set fullClasspath in Runtime <<= (fullClasspath in Runtime) map
  {_.files.filterNot(_.getName.containsSlice("asm")).classpath}
```